# Nested Queries in SQLite3 Android

Tags: android, datetime, insert, sqlite

I want to execute a query something like :

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(datetime('now'));
```

Where `MyTable` has schema:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
mydate DATETIME
)
```

When executed in SQLite Manager query runs perfectly inserting the current datetime value in `mydate` column of `MyTable`.

But when executed using

```
ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
cv.put(MyTable.mydate,"datetime('now')");
getContentResolver.insert(MyTable.CONTENT_URI,cv);
```

The value in mydate reads **datetime('now')** and not the actual current date and time.

I am performing all this from a ContentProvider.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use SQLite functions in calls to `query()`, whether `query()` is called on a `SQLiteDatabase` or on a `ContentResolver`.

You can embed calls to SQLite functions in a SQL statement executed via `rawQuery()` on a `SQLiteDatabase`, but that may not help you much if you wish to wrap your database access in a content provider.

The simplest answer is for you to adjust your schema such that `mydate` has a default value of `datetime('now')`, then just ignore that column when you are inserting your data.

Comment: Nice thanx. I read your books sir :) You have suggested nice approach.

Comment: @Shardul: You're welcome. I use that default value trick all the time for the "created at" value in my database rows. Very handy!