# Can I use Query in a Query?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Let's say I have 2 tables, `Contacts` and `Phones`. User can input name for `Contacts` query. I use this

```
Cursor cur = cr.query(
    CONTACT_URI, 
    new String[] { CONTACT_COLUMN_ID, CONTACT_COLUMN_NAME }, 
    CONTACT_COLLUMN_NAME + " LIKE '%" + search + "%'", 
    null, 
    null
);
```

And then I want to query from `Phones` for the matching contact I got from first query.  I can use third parameter to input my condition such as "WHERE _ID = xx OR _ID = xx" and so on...

#### The question is,

Can I use first query/cursor as condition for next query?  My second query is like this :

```
Cursor pCur = cr.query(
    PHONE_URI, 
    new String[] { PHONE_COLUMN_ID, PHONE_COLUMN_DATA }, 
    null, 
    null, 
    null
);
```

EDIT : extra note, I'm querying from device database, so I only have Uri to use.

EDIT 2 : alternatively, I can use this

```
Cursor pCur = cr.query(
    PHONE_URI, 
    new String[] { PHONE_COLUMN_ID, PHONE_COLUMN_DATA }, 
    PHONE_COLUMN_ID, 
    selectedIds, 
    null
);
```

but if selectedIds got too big, I got this exception

```
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.laac.comp.phonelookup/com.laac.comp.phonelookup.PhoneContactLookup}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x199d7c0
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1816)
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1837)
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1033)
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x199d7c0
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:158)
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQueryInternal(ContentProviderNative.java:372)
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:408)
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:264)
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     at com.laac.comp.phonelookup.PhoneContactLookup.getContactWithPhone(PhoneContactLookup.java:255)
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     at com.laac.comp.phonelookup.PhoneContactLookup.onCreate(PhoneContactLookup.java:84)
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1780)
07-13 11:06:48.496: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25137):     ... 11 more
```

`PhoneContactLookup.java:255` is my query on EDIT 2

Comment: Please see this post, may be its helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723848/nested-queries-in-sqlite3-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thought is part of the comment:

```
cr.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + CONTACT_URI + "as cu LEFT JOIN " + PHONE_URI + " as pu ON  (cu.PHONE_COLUMN_ID = pu.PHONE_COLUMN_ID) WHERE CONTACT_COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%"+search+"%'");
```

second thought is based on your edit 2 I think you need to first create a format query string that has ? in the right places to be filled in by the selected ids list, so I think it would be something like:

```
if(selectedIds.length==0)
    return;

String formatString = "PHONE_COLUMN_ID=?";
for(int i=0;i<selectedIds.length-1;i++)
{
    formatString+=" OR PHONE_COLUMN_ID=? ";
}
Cursor pCur = cr.query(
    PHONE_URI, 
    new String[] { PHONE_COLUMN_ID, PHONE_COLUMN_DATA }, 
    formatString, 
    selectedIds, 
    null
);
```

Comment: I can use Uri as table name? 

and I can't find rawQuery Function in ContentResolver

Comment: Hi Tek, Sorry was looking at the SQLiteDatabase didn't realize you were using a different class, anyhow how about the second solution, seems that should still work?

Comment: selection A filter declaring which rows to return, formatted as an SQL WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE itself). Passing null will return all rows for the given URI.
selectionArgs You may include ?s in selection, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs, in the order that they appear in the selection. The values will be bound as Strings.

Comment: your second though maybe a good idea, if It don't involve many data. because I got this

07-13 11:41:38.966: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25687): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 11:41:38.966: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25687): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.laac.comp.phonelookup/com.laac.comp.phonelookup.PhoneContactLookup}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: too many SQL variables:

Comment: Interesting stuff on it here: http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html think you're running into rule 6 maybe, would have it trace out the format string and see what it's building and if it seems valid based on your dataset, if you need it to deal with more than 100 perhaps split up the array and do multiple queries for each set of 100 parameters then recombine the results, not the cleanest but will probably work

Comment: seems it is the best way for now.... your answer don't give the direct answer, but at least it direct me to the right path :) your answer deserve a acceptance. Thanks

Comment: no problem sorry I didn't have a completely direct answer it's difficult with limited information (DB definitions, variable types etc.) anyhow hope you get it worked out if not post back and give more feedback on the types of objects being used and the output you're currently getting when tracing the variables being built or more code in general and I can do more real world testing